# Regex match anything preceding a sequence of dots

Tags: regex

I'd like to make a regex that matches anything that is succeeded by four points or more:

```
asdf.......
```

Would match to `asdf`.

I've tried with:

```
.+?(?=\.{4,})
```

but it only discards the last four dots, so it matches `asdf...`.

How can it be done?

Comment: Try [`(.*?)\.{4,}`](https://regex101.com/r/BecPGk/1) and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: The least modification from your current solution would be to use a class that excludes literal dots instead of `.` : `[^.]+(?=\.{4,})`. That said, Wiktor's solution is likely to be more efficient.

Comment: If you cannot use capture group then use: `.*[^.](?=\.{4})`

Comment: Difference between anubhava's solution and mine : mine will fail if your searched data can contain dots (e.g. matching against `123.456....` will only return `456` with my solution, while it will correctly return `123.456` with anubhava's), but is more efficient if there can't be dots in the searched data (mine matches your sample data in 12 steps according to regex101, while anubhava's take 29 steps because `.*` matches up to the end of the string before backtracking until `[^.]` matches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.+?(?=\.{4,})` regex matches `asdf` in `asdf.......` since it finds 4 or more dots right after the value, but since the `\.{4,}` is inside a non-consuming pattern, the `.......` remains to be checked and the first `.` in that substring is matched again since `.+?` matches any 1 or more chars other than line break chars, but as few as possible. Same happens with the second and third `.`s since they all are followed with 4+ commas.

What you may do is either make the dot matching part consuming and capture the `.+?` (then the value you need will be in Group 1):

```
(.+?)\.{4,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BecPGk/2)

Here, `(.*?)` is a capturing group matching 0+ chars (use `*` instead of `+` to match 1 or more) other than line break chars and `\.{4,}` will match and consuming 4 or more `.` chars (not allowing to check for a match when inside the dots).

Comment: If this is in a larger document, for instance: `Hi there..... Hel"lo.there abc....` it will happily match the larger sequence of dots behind it

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!\.+)(.+?)\.{4,}$
```

Captures anything preceding 4 or more dots, but also makes sure that the string isn't *all* dots

If you're searching through a larger document:

```
(?!\.).+?(?<!\.)(?=\.{4,})
```

See here for the [first example](https://regex101.com/r/8MlplM/2)

See here for the [second example](https://regex101.com/r/8MlplM/1)